Type arguments of inner generic classes in Java
JLS  4.5.2:

If any of the type arguments in the parameterization of C are
wildcards, then:
• The types of the fields, methods, and constructors in C<T1,...,Tn>
are the types of the fields, methods, and constructors in the capture
conversion of C<T1,...,Tn> (§5.1.10).
• Let D be a (possibly generic) class or interface declaration in C.
Then the type of D in C<T1,...,Tn> is D where, if D is generic, all
type arguments are unbounded wildcards.

I don't quite understand what the last sentence means.This sentence seems to be saying that the type argument of an inner generic class must be an unbounded wildcard.But it seems that this is not the case.
Could someone please explain this passage to me in detail and give an example?
Thank you for your reading and answer.

What makes you think that it is not the case?

@Maurice Perry For example, there is code like Outer<?>.Inner<Integer> inner = outer.new Inner<>(); , I think the type argument of the inner class is not a wildcard.

As the text immediately below it states: "This is of no consequence".
To make this clearer:
class Outer<T extends Number> {
  class Inner<Z extends List<T>> {}

  void foo(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Inner) { ... }
  }
}

...



It refers to the notion of referring to the type Inner within the context of a parameterization of Outer.
This is irrelevant (see the note at the end of JLS §4.5.2), except in instanceof, where it is irrelevant in a different way because instanceof does not (and cannot due to erasure) actually do anything with any generics:
List<?> x = new ArrayList<String>();
if (x instanceof List<Integer>) {
  System.out.println("None of this works");
}

The above code doesn't compile; the compiler knows what you mean and won't compile it because its nonsense (x is a variable that points at an instance of some sort of list; that instance does not know its own generics bounds, so instanceof cannot do what you ask it to here).
The point is, the compiler first needs to understand what you mean before it can tell you that what you want is not possible. That note you are asking about is about how the compiler goes about understanding what you mean. It is of no consequence because the result is the same: You can't do that with instanceof.

I find this explanation inadequate. The antecedent is "any of the type arguments in the parameterization of C are wildcards", but there is no wildcards in the Outer/Inner example. There is also no parameterisation of Outer/Inner either. Everything is in the declaration of Outer. The spec is referring to situations where you have e.g. an Outer<?>, isn't it?

From what I understand, instanceof is the sole exception of "this is of no consequence", i.e. this is of consequence in an instanceof expression. What consequence does it have then? The spec apparently says that this is because there is no capture conversion in instanceof, so I imagine this is something to do with the left hand side of instanceof...

Could you tell me why there is code like Outer<?>.Inner<Integer> inner = outer.new Inner<>()?I think the type argument of the inner class is not a wildcard.

@user24723440 You're working with capture-converted types there.

@Sweeper JLS §4.5.2 is expressing the idea that any references to the type D within the context of C act like D<?> even if you don't explicitly write <?>; but this doesn't actually come up because the rule doesn't apply to capture-converted types which means it only applies to instanceof where it is  moot because instanceof does not let you add generics. I admit I'm at a loss as to when this line in the JLS ever actually matters. It more feels like it is stating an implementation detail which shouldn't be in the JLS.

Do you mean converting from ? to Integer? But isn't capture conversion converting an unbounded wildcard to a type variable? As far as I know, Integer is not a type variable. Could you please explain this in more detail? Thank you!
